# Viewing files after adding with PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp, asset-library

I am attempting to upload images to my site assets folder using the Add-PnPFile powershell command. The command executes successfully and I am able to go to the ServerRelativeUrl and see the image, but I am not able to see the images when navigating to the Site Assets folder inside of Sharepoint.

The following is the command I am running:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://mysite.sharepoint.com
Add-PnPFile -FileName test.png -Folder "Site Assets" -Stream $stream
```

Where $stream is a System.IO.MemoryStream that contains the image.

Here is the result of running the command:

```
Name     Type Items/Size Last Modified      
----     ---- ---------- -------------      
test.png File      33827 7/8/2020 7:47:31 PM
```

The ServerRelativeUrl returns /Site Assets/test.png, and going to mysite.sharepoint.com/Site Assets/test.png shows the image correctly, but it does not show up in the Site Assets folder in my site. Is there a different folder path I am supposed to use to upload it to the correct folder?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sample test script, you may try it.

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "Password" 
$siteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/modernteamlee"
#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

Add-PnPFile -Path "C:\Lee\panda.jpg" -Folder "SiteAssets" -NewFileName "panda.jpg"
Write-Host "-----------"
```